# Using pre-made RSA keys

Tags: security, encryption, rsa

I am trying to set a licensing system on a software that I made. The idea is that the client receives a copy of my software, the software checks it's hardware ID or some other unique identifier of the specific computer, and then uses asymmetric encryption with a public key to generate an activation code from that identifier. The client then sends the activation code to me, which I use with my private key to create a signature, which I send back to him, and the software confirms it. It also checks regularly if the unique identifier is still correct. I hope I understand that part right.

Copying from [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsapkcs1signaturedeformatter?view=netframework-4.7.2), I wrote a basic code in VB that does the both creating the signature (which should be done on my computer) and the checking of the signature (done on client's computer):

```
    Function RSAoperations(hardwareID As String)
    Dim hashValue() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(hardwareID)
    Dim sha256 As SHA256 = SHA256Managed.Create()
    Dim hash() As Byte = sha256.ComputeHash(hashValue)
    Dim RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider()

    'create signature
    Dim RSAFormatter As New RSAPKCS1SignatureFormatter(RSA)
    RSAFormatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256")
    Dim SignedHash() As Byte
    SignedHash = RSAFormatter.CreateSignature(hash)

    'check signature
    Dim RSADeformatter = New RSAPKCS1SignatureDeformatter(RSA)
    RSADeformatter.SetHashAlgorithm("SHA256")
    If RSADeformatter.VerifySignature(hash, SignedHash) Then
        Console.WriteLine("The signature was verified.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("The signature was not verified.")
    End If

    Dim Parameters As New RSAParameters
    Parameters = RSA.ExportParameters(True)

    'display the private key. Base64 encode the text to make display easier

    Debug.Print("private key: " & Convert.ToBase64String(Parameters.D))

    'display the public key. Base64 encode the text to make display easier

    Debug.Print("public key: " & Convert.ToBase64String(Parameters.Modulus))
End Function
```

On each run of this function, the Dim RSA As New RSACryptoServiceProvider()
creates a new RSA object with new set of public and private keys. But since I want to embed the public key in the copy of the software that the client will receive, I need to somehow create a pair of keys once, write them down, and make RSA accept that pre-made public key on client's computer. As I imagine, I must create that RSA object on both machines, but tell one of them to use a pre-made public key, while telling the other to use a pre-made private key. I went through RSA API many times, and I cannot find any methods that relate to such functionality.

I am getting a feeling that I am somehow misunderstanding the whole process and what I need to do to achieve my goal. Can somebody please help me clear this up? I found numerous examples of RSA in use on the internet, but none of them explain how RSA keys are shared between two machines.

Answer (score 1):

Let me try to break down your question for understanding.

- You are trying to create a RSA based licensing as the following steps:
- You are getting some details (hardwareid ... etc.,) from the client's computer through your software and create a SHA256 hash
- Then sign the hash using a RSA Key pair (Now, here is the catch. You can sign the hash using a pre-made RSA Key pair, but just embed your RSA Public / Private key into the software and create the signature using the embedded RSA Private Key.)
- (Along with the application's public / private key pair, also embed another public key into the application to which you hold the private key.)
- Once you receive the signature along with the hash value, you can verify and sign it again with you private key (Which you have to keep it secure and assume it is in your possession only).
- Once the software receives the your personal private key signed hash value, it can verify the hash with the stored RSA Public key and it can proceed to function as required.

I hope the process is clear. There is no need to create a new key pair every time since you will not be able to transport / share them to you in plaintext. Else it will be a slight overkill for you to encrypt the keypair and then get them to your system (which is not recommended since any good reverser will be able to crack the embedded password.) There are other methods, but I do not want to overload the topic with different thoughts.

Also, the following code project articles should give you some thoughts on using RSA based product licensing / activation approaches etc.,

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4940/Using-XML-Digital-Signatures-for-Application-Licen

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16506/Product-Activation-Based-on-RSA-Signatures

Please be informed that the protection / licensing is as strong as the application's binary protection. If the embedded RSA Public Key inside your executable / program can be altered, then the licensing scheme can be defeated.

I hope the above is helpful for you to achieve your licensing scheme.

Comment: You can't sign with a public key.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Suri. I am looking into these articles, they will take some time for me to understand. Would you comment on what James said? Is it true that it's impossible to sign with a public key? If so, how would your suggested approach work?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's correct.Using the public key, you can encrypt the data and not sign it. You could encrypt the data using the public key and only you will able to decrypt it using the private key. Then you could sign the data and send it back as a response

Comment: Thank you. I managed to get it working. You were very helpful.

Comment: Care to write a simple steps on the process which you've followed for the benefit of others? I am sure it will of help to anyone who reads this thread. Also, please mark the helpful answer as the solved if you have achieved what you were expecting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you simply need to generate the keypair once on the server and securely persist it. In addition you need to call `ExportParameters(False)`, serialize the resulting RSAParameters object and then base64 encode the bytes to create a String. Then hard-code this string in your client software and reverse the process when you run the client: base64-decode the string, deserialize the bytes into an RSAParameters object, create an RSA object and run the ImportParameters method to import the public key.

Note that I am not saying your scheme is secure, just explaining what steps you need to perform to carry it out. To make a security assessment you should consult an expert and provide them with the full details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have been experimenting with this for the past several days. If you don't mind, I have a question. When using RSA.ImportParameters(parameters) on client's computer, the only value I'm setting in Parameters is the Modulus (public key). However, as the rest of values are not set, the ImportParameters function fails. Do I have to use ExportParameters beforehand to set all values of the Parameters, and overwrite the Modulus only? Is this the correct and safe way of using RSA?